# function after andengine EntityModifier completed

Tags: andengine

In the game menu i want the menu items slide away from the screen and then scene changes. 
I can't seem to make it work one by one, they seems to execute the same time so there is no time for the menu items to move.

```
@Override
public void onBackKeyPressed()
{
//  SceneManager.getInstance().loadMenuScene(engine);
    if(hasChildScene()) {
        /* Remove the menu and reset it. */
        menuOut();
        this.gameMenuChildScene.back();
    } else {
        /* Attach the menu. */
        createGameMenuChildScene();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is this EntityModifier you mention in your title?

Answer (score 0):

The AndEngine Cookbook designed an animated game menu by making it an Entity and attaching it to the HUD, no Scene changes at all.
Otherwise, why don't you make a Callback once the animation is complete to change the scene?

-Sorry i can't comment yet and i wanted to help

Answer (score 0):

U can do it like this: where 2f is time in seconds. It's not nice but it should work.

```
this.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(2f, new ITimerCallback() {
    public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
        resourcesManager.engine.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                    //change scene here
    }
}));
```

You also have isFinished() method in your EntityModifier. You can initialize onUpdate and check isFinished() method. When it returns true you will change the scene. It more elastic and nicer way to do it. I can't verify it right now so you have to check the soultion yourself.